# Executing document's Javascript function by using third-party Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

Say I have localhost/site/index.php with one Javascript function and one button:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function(){
        alert('Hello eveeryone!');
    }
</script>


</head>

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="my_function();" />Here is my button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to execute `my_function()` without clicking button - by using **some kind of bookmarklet or similar kind of in-browser residing Javascript** or anything else that not implies clicking on button-default interacting with document's Javascript?

EDIT:
Better explanation of problem:
can I use localhost/site/script.php to trigger above mentioned my_function that resides in localhost/site/index.php?

Comment: A bit vague... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you're talking about User Scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the body `onload` function:

```
<body onload="my_function();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery trigger.

```
$('button').trigger('click')
```

The button's onclick handler gets called. (Actually ALL buttons' onclick handlers are called. So maybe make a class or id for the specific button to target it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the web page is not yours so you can't modify it directly.  So, if you have a way of executing javascript in the context of the page (bookmarklet or plug-in or something like that) and you know what the name of the click handler function is, then you can just execute the click handler directly with:

```
my_function()
```

---

EDIT: because now it appears from comments that you are actually asking a question about the security of your own web page.

You cannot prevent the execution of javascript functions in your own web page.  There are numerous ways for people to inject code into your page from their own browser that can call anything in your web page that is globally accessible.  You cannot prevent that.  It's possible to make it more difficult to directly call event handlers, but this just makes it slightly more work, but does not prevent it.

Security MUST be implemented on your server - it cannot be implemented in a web page.  A browser client web page is NOT a secure environment.  It can be freely modified.  Whatever you are trying to protect from must be implemented on the server.

Comment: jfriend00 can you make your answer more clear, please? I'm concerned about my website security - I have javascript function that should not be executed out of context of my website, if that's possible, I should change something. And I would like to know how can that kind of execution be accomplished. Thanks.

Comment: @Miloshio - Geez.  If this is a question about the security of your own web page, then you should PUT THAT IN THE QUESTION.  You would have then gotten answers about security instead of what you did.  Why is it that people don't state the problem/question they actually have?

Comment: @Miloshio - I added some new information to my answer about web page security.

Comment: thanks. I assumed that's possible. But: "There are numerous ways for people to inject code into your page from their own browser that can call anything in your web page that is globally accessible." - I'm learning JS and I'm curious about how to accomplish exactly what I asked in example - how to run index.php's my_function() without clicking the button and having access to modify index.php itself?

Comment: @Miloshio - There are lots of ways: bookmarklet, browser add-on, GreaseMonkey script, proxy that modifies the page, javascript debug console and execute a function, javascript debugger.  I still don't understand what your question actually is.